# Subscribe to watch the video wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have added a video on my WordPress website and I want user first subscribe only then they should be able to play the video. I tried some Subscription plugin but not able to do it. Is there any way to do it in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following plugin in order to achieve the same functionality.

[WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/)

[Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/)

[Groups for WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/groups-woocommerce/)

After the installation , you need to create a group and assign a page marked to that group so that only authorized customers from that group only can see the video page.

Assign the group to the subscription so that User will automatically added to the group after purchase of subscription.

You can also achieve the same functionality with gravity form subscriptions plugin.